# sharepoint web service

Tags: sharepoint, list, service

I'm trying to access the version history data from a sharepoint list with a web service.
I'm able to get the 'list' data, but I'm having troubles with accessing the version history.

Any help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetVersionCollection method of ListsWebService